# Identifying the tangent space with $R^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have been reading a book about Riemannian geometry and at some point the author says that since the metric of the manifold defines an inner product on $T_pM$ we can think of $T_pM$ as the Euclidean n-space $\mathbb{R}^n$. When he says what does he really mean, is there some kinda of isomorphism or something?.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is nothing deep here; the vector space $T_p M$ has dimension $n$, thus you can identify it with $\mathbb R^n$. Concretely, if you have a coordinate system $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$, then you have a basis of $T_p M$ given by 
$$\tag{1}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}, \ldots, \frac{\partial }{\partial x_n}; $$
so you can identify the vector 
$$
v_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\ldots + v_n\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}
$$
with the $n$-uple 
$$
(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n)\in \mathbb R^n.$$
Of course, if you change coordinates, the identification will change accordingly.

Steffen remarks in comments that this is only a algebraic isomorphism and that it needs not preserve the scalar product. This means that it needs NOT be the case that
$$
\langle v, w\rangle_{T_p M}=\sum_{j=1}^n v_jw_j.$$ 
For this to be true, the basis of $T_p M$ should be **orthonormal**, and there is no guarantee that (1) is. However, as in any scalar product space, given an arbitrary basis we can always construct an orthonormal one via the Gram-Schmidt algorithm. (This orthonormal basis might not come from a coordinate system, though).

Comment: This is not a isomorphism to the Euclidean vector space $\mathbb R^n$, since it does not map the scalar product of $T_p M$ onto the euclidean scalar product on $\mathbb R^n$. (A specific choice of the chart would be required to achieve this.)

Comment: Oh, you are right. This answer concerns the smooth structure only, and it disregards the Riemannian one. (@SteffenPlunder: )